# Making a link by changing added random input by using variables

Tags: javascript, html, brackets

Quick apology if it's super raw and beginer-like. I'm trying to make a custom link that changes depending on what input you put. That input however has to change as well to make that link. The begging is the same every time which is "https://whatever.com/edu-" then you add a custom group number that you typed in, which is always starting with lowercase letter, then "/", group name again with same requirements, "-", then name with all lower case letters, ".", first lower case letter of surname you typed in ".com". If it's not hard, I'd appreciate the same code not being turned too advanced one as I'm still only covered basics of js, mainly, var/slice/string.

I've tried giving them variables seperatly, but then I'm not quite sure how to pick them seperately to make it one function so I stacked them together with hopes it would work but for some reason it doesn't load the answer I need. My guess is, that I may have messed up the function with var.

```js
function MyFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
  var name2 = name.toLowerCase();
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML;
  var lname2 = lname.toLowercase();
  var lname = str.substring(0, 1);
  var group = document.getElementById("group").innerHTML;
  var group2 = group.toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML + "group" + "/" + "group" + "-" + "name" + "." + "lname" + ".com"
}
```

```html
<form>
  Vardas:
  <input id="name" type="text"> Pavardė:
  <input id="lname" type="text"> Grupė:
  <input id="group" type="text">
</form>

<button onLoad="MyFunction()">
  <input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="MyFunction()" />
</button>
<br>

<div id="result">
  https://whatever.com/edu-
</div>
```

The result webpage if let's say I type in Vardas: Darija, Pavardė: Galdikaitė, Group: IT15. You click on button and the link underneath it changes to "https://whatever.com/edu-it15/it15-darija.g.com". Thank you in advance for the trouble if what I have so far is not right at all. P.S. I'm using Brackets.

Comment: Instead of .innerHTML use .value, as you want to read the value of that input, not it's HTML content.

Comment: And to get the value of a variable you just need to write it. So not `+ "group" +`, but rather `+ group +`.

Comment: `str` is not defined. You also have a typo. It's `.toLowerCase` and not `.toLowercase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an input inside a button onload for input should suffice, `toLowerCase` had a typo, you can store the original link value when the page loads:

```js
const originalLink = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;

function MyFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase();
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1);
  var group = document.getElementById("group").value.toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = originalLink.trim() + "group" + "/" + group + "-" + name + "." + lname + ".com"
}
```

```html
<form>
  Vardas:
  <input id="name" type="text"> Pavardė:
  <input id="lname" type="text"> Grupė:
  <input id="group" type="text">

<input onload="MyFunction()" type="button" value="Click here" onclick="MyFunction()" />
</form>

<br>

<div id="result">
  https://whatever.com/edu-
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the wanted string and take the value from the inputs andadd the result to `innerHTML`.

Just take either a button or an input for submitting.

```js
function MyFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase(),
      lname = document.getElementById("lname").value[0].toLowerCase(),
      group = document.getElementById("group").value.toUpperCase();

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += `${group}/${group}-${name}.${lname}.com`;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Vardas:
  <input id="name" type="text"> Pavardė:
  <input id="lname" type="text"> Grupė:
  <input id="group" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="MyFunction()" />
</form>
<br>
<div id="result">https://whatever.com/edu-</div>
```

Comment: You have a few issues in your code. One: multiple clicking on "Click here" button will completely destroy the link, as it will keep appending bad data. It needs a 'reset' state as you see it all other answers. Secondly, stop encouraging developers to use template literal as its not supported by all browsers (eg: IE).

Comment: right, the function does not contain validation and no handling of storing the link string, which does not build a clickable link as well. by all repsects, the time with IE is over.

Comment: Indeed, but some private companies internal web applications must run only in IE (due to security reasons). Please believe me that I hate it the most, since I always have to write code that works on IE too, and that's why I pointed that out. I was so happy when I first met template literal, and soon dissapointed because of damn IE X(. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .innerHTML use .value, as you want to read the value of that input, not it's HTML content. Also, when you want to update the content of the element, use **equal** operator `element.innerHTML = "<b>new value</b>`". Check the example bellow.

```js
function MyFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase(),
  lname = document.getElementById("lname").value.toLowerCase(),
  group = document.getElementById("group").value.toLowerCase();
  // If you want to use only the first letter of the lname as stated in your example with "https://whatever.com/edu-it15/it15-darija.g.com", uncomment the next line
  // lname = lname.substr(0,1);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  "https://whatever.com/edu-" + group + "/" + group + "-" + name + "." + lname + ".com"
}
```

```html
<form>
  Vardas:
  <input id="name" type="text"> Pavardė:
  <input id="lname" type="text"> Grupė:
  <input id="group" type="text">
</form>

<button onLoad="MyFunction()">
  <input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="MyFunction()" />
</button>
<br>

<div id="result">
  https://whatever.com/edu-
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax mistakes. See the following refactored code, you will see concatenated lines.

```js
function MyFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase();
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1);
  var group = document.getElementById("group").value.toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = group + "/" + group + "-" + name + "." + lname + ".com"
}
```

```html
<form>
  Vardas:
  <input id="name" type="text"> Pavardė:
  <input id="lname" type="text"> Grupė:
  <input id="group" type="text">
</form>

<button onLoad="MyFunction()">
        <input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="MyFunction()" />
    </button>
<br>

<div id="result">
  https://whatever.com/edu-
</div>
```